# Regex to Allow various currency formats

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
[0-9]+,[0-9]{2}
```

https://regexr.com/3joum

And i can enter

```
10,00
1,00,
100,00,
1000,00
```

But i also want to have this:

```
1.000,00
10.000,00
100.000,00
1000.000.00
```

and so on... to that be valid also. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you didn't bother to include the regexp in question in your post; there is no guarantee that external link will work in the future, and the question would loose all value if it doesn't.

Comment: Put the comma in a character class and add a period. https://regex101.com/r/XZS12a/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to tell what rules exactly you're looking to follow with your regex. How about this?

```
([0-9]+[,.])+[0-9]{2}(,)?
```

This regex will allow you to match currency that uses either a , or a . and can even end in a , like in some of your examples.

Comment: im using european format currency and user can enter 1000,00 i formated and displa him 1.000,00